# Generate random values for different types

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, casting, sql-types

I'm generating scripts in C# to test **CRUD** operations.

To do this I'm generating programmatically for example INSERT scripts that depending on the type returned from the ***system catalog*** (eg varchar (200), binary, tinyint ect.) 
Would generate random values​​. My *idea* was following:

- Column1  (varchar(200))
- Column2  (tinyint)
- Column3  (bigint)
- ...
- ColumnN  (binary,int, sql_variant....)

In **C#** i generate a Random Number that Cast as

123456 random number generated

```
INSERT INTO table_test (Column1,Column2,Column3,...)
SELECT CAST(123456 as varchar(200)),CAST(123456 as tinyint) ,CAST(123456 as bigint) ,...
```

Obviously my method is **not** the **best** as risk making arithmetic overflow in text and not in full all the characters of varchar. What is your advice without having to do all cases?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against doing this. Unit test your data access layer, but don't test your database; surely Microsoft have already done that for you?

Comment: It's not properly a Unit Test. It's a WinForm that generate me a script to test database

Comment: I still see no reason to test the actual database. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm changing all my trigger and i want to test it. But maybe you are going OT.

Comment: You can use red-gate tools. http://www.red-gate.com